# to prove $x^2 + y^2+1\ge xy + y + x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$x^2 + y^2+1\ge xy + y + x$$

$x$ and $ y$ belong to all real numbers

my attempt

$(u-2)^2\ge0\Rightarrow \frac{u^2}{4}+1\ge u $

let $u=x+y\Rightarrow \frac{(x+y)^2}{4}+1\ge x+y$

$\Rightarrow (x+y)^2+1\ge \frac{3}{4}(x+y)^2+(x+y)$

$but \frac{(x+y)^2}{4} \ge xy $ by AM-GM inequality

$\Rightarrow (x+y)^2+1\ge \frac{3}{4}(x+y)^2+(x+y)\ge3xy+(x+y)$

hence  $\Rightarrow x^2 + y^2+2xy+1\ge 3xy+x+y$

are the steps correct and is there any other better way??

Comment: "But $\frac{(x+y)^2}{4} \ge xy $" - why?

Comment: Type/bounds of x,y?

Comment: @DietrichBurde That is because $(x-y)^{2} \geq 0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, I know. But it should be mentioned in the solution.

Comment: @DietrichBurde by  inequality of arithmetic and geometric mean, followed by squaring on both sides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c=x^2+y^2+1-(xy+x+y)$

$\iff x^2-x(1+y)+1-y+y^2-c=0$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

i.e., $$(1+y)^2\ge4(1-y+y^2-c)\iff4c\ge3(1-y)^2$$  which is $\ge0$ for real $y$

Alternatively,

$$ x^2-x(1+y)+1-y+y^2=\left(x-\dfrac{1+y}2\right)^2+\dfrac{3(1-y)^2}4$$

Comment: $x^2-x(1+y)+1-y+y^2 = (x-\frac{1+y}{2})^2 - \frac{(1+y)^2}{4} +1 -y +y^2$. Where did the $\frac{3(1-y)^2}{4}$ come from?

Comment: @Edmund,  $$4(1-y+y^2)-(1+y)^2=?$$  Am I missing anything ?

Comment: No, I understand now. $\frac{4(1-y+y^2)-(1+y)^2}{4} = \frac{4-4y+4y^2-(1+2y+y^2)}{4}= \frac{4-4y+4y^2-1-2y-y^2}{4}= \frac{3-6y+3y^2}{4}=\frac{3(1-y)^2}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

Prove
$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+1-x-xy-y\geq 0.$$
$$f_x=2x-1-y$$
$$f_y=2y-1-x$$
$$f_x=0\implies y=2x-1$$
$$f_y=0\implies x=2y-1$$
$$y=2(2y-1)-1=4y-3\implies y=1$$
$$x=2(2x-1)-1=4x-3\implies x=1$$

There's a stationary point at $(1,1)$.
$$f_{xx}=2,f_{xy}=f_{yx}=-1,f_{yy}=2.$$

Since $$f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2=4-(-1)^2=3>0\text{ and }f_{xx}=2>0$$
then that stationary point is a minimum. Furthermore $f(1,1)=0\geq 0$.